# How can I open a file from my Raspberry pi using ssh onto my local host, a normal Windows 10 laptop?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, atom-editor

I have already set up ssh with my raspberry pi 3 and my laptop, but now I want to open a file from the raspberry pi onto atom on my windows 10 laptop, and when I save the file in atom on my Windows 10 laptop, I want it to save to and update the file on the raspberry pi. I don't want to just copy a file over to the windows 10 laptop, and I don't want to create a file on the laptop and transfer it to the raspberry pi. I've already tried following these instructions, which use the remote-atom package in atom: https://atom.io/packages/remote-atom, and when I enter

```
$ ratom index.html
```

into the terminal using ssh after following all the proper instructions, it doesn't open the file from my raspberry pi onto atom as expected. Instead, the terminal just skips to the next line, and I'm not able to enter any commands, and nothing opened in Atom. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just share a directory on Windows or on the Pi with the other machine using Samba? No need to cooy anything anywhere, you can edit the same file from either machine.

Comment: Thanks man, I'm pretty new to Linux so I hadn't ever heard of Samba, it works like a charm.

Comment: Excellent! Good luck with your project.